# How to get coordinates from dataframe and put in new dataframe?

Tags: r

I have dataframe `coords_pa` with two columns(x=longitude, y = latitude).
For example:

`coords_pa <-data.frame(x=c(35.75004,41.41671,67.41672,49.58338),y=c(63.58333,63.41666,38.75004, 54.58338))`

How could I create new dataframe `coords_pa_new` with two columns (x,y), but it will contain only coordinates with condition: x>40 and y>64?

I tried to find and succeed this task, but I do not know how to convert it in one dataframe:

`kf = ifelse(coords_pa$y>64,1,0)`

`newdata = cbind(kf,coords_pa)`

`ff = ifelse(coords_pa$x>40,1,0)`

`newdata1 = cbind(ff,coords_pa)`

Comment: Do you want `x>40` **and** `y>64` or `x>40` **or** `y>64`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subset `coords_pa` using `[` by combining both conditions with `&`:

```
coords_pa[coords_pa$x > 40 & coords_pa$y > 64,]
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can subset, like so:

```
coords_pa[coords_pa$x > 40 | coords_pa$y > 64,]
```

The `|` operator specifies that x > 40 OR y > 64. If you rather mean that **both** conditions must be satisfied, change the operator to `&` (but there's no result in your sample)

Comment: Not much difference to my answer exchanging `&` with `|`. In the question I can read *x>40 and y>64*.

Comment: But I guess it can't be right as the result's an empty df